# How to increase additional disk size with ext4 file system on Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have additional disk of 500GB that mounted into instance with path /mnt/disks/ssd-1/www with ext4 as file system, no partitioned, and have been used 400GB.
Usually for booting disk, i will use **sudo growpart /dev/sda 1** and **sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1** to increase disk space.

But never done for additional disk. Is it possible to update additional disk size?

Comment: Yes and no. The answer depends on how the disk is partitioned. How is your secondary disk partitioned? Which file systems are on each partition? Which file system do you want to resize?

Comment: @JohnHanley, its not partitioned. when i run command **sudo df -Th** its showed:
**/dev/sdb       ext4      492G  393G   99G  81% /mnt/disks/ssd-1**

Comment: Google Cloud Linux images include resize tools. The same steps in your question are the solution for most file system types. Edit your question with a problem that you are trying to solve. Note: for the boot disk, Google executes resize automatically on persistent disk resize on system reboot.

Comment: @JohnHanley, do you mean the same command that used to resize boot data disk can be used to resize non-boot data disk? The disk used on production. If it possible, i want to resize the additional disk without downtime.

Comment: Resizing a file system requires downtime. Edit your question to clearly state a problem instead of using comments to **grow** a question.

Comment: You can edit disk size directly with the GCP webapp.

Answer (score 0):

https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/disks

Select your disk, then click Edit.

You may need to have the disk not currently mounted to perform some actions.